# Which pronoun is correct to use in this sentence and why?

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns

Which pronoun is correct to use in this sentence and why?

(1)Are you sure the guys are okay with **me** coming?

(2)Are you sure the guys are okay with **my** coming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are both okay.  The sentence "I come" is object of "with" here, but an object may not be a finite sentence.  So "I come" has to be nominalized, i.e., converted to a NP.  The nominalizers Poss+ing and Acc+ing (meaning that the verb is changed to the -ing gerund form and the subject "I" is changed to a possessive or accusative form) are ordinarily alternatives, though sometimes one sounds better.  In your example, they sound equally good, to me.

Answer (score 0):

The second one is correct, because you always want to use the possessive before a gerund. Coming is a noun so you need an adjective beforehand, which is my instead of me.

Comment: No. You need to research the ACC-ing as well as the POSS-ing structures, both endorsed by reputable grammars.